# Perl API version v5.14.0 of DBI does not match v5.16.0 at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm

Tags: linux, perl, dbi

I got this exception when i run a perl script in Linux. I am not an expert in perl, and i have searched for a solution and they all wanted to rebuild/re-install the perl and i do not have an access either.
so could anyone tell what to do without rebuilding?

**edit: output of perl -V**
perl: warning: setting locale failed.
perl: warning: please check your locale setting lc_all = (unset)
language = (unset)

Comment: You seem to have multiple perl versions installed, or perhaps did an incomplete upgrade of your perl? What is `perl -V` output? For example, it could be that a user perl is using the paths of the system perl, thus finding incompatible libraries.

Comment: new version is v5.16 and i don't know how to get missing libraries? as i told you i can't rebuild the Perl, but what if i put an intermediate server where i can install the Perl v5.16 with a full access and copy this file dynaloader to the current server where the problem is? i hope there would be another solution

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the output of `perl -V` (uppercase V!), which should show configuration data for the Perl 5.16. Perhaps this can be solved by correcting a few environment variables, no recompilation needed.

Comment: You are trying to load a module installed by 5.14 using Perl 5.16. Perhaps you have env var `PERL5LIB` set to something bad?

Comment: @amon thr output of perl -V is very long. do you want me to search for a certain var.?

Comment: the DynaLoader.pm which fires the exception doesn't exist in the output of perl -V . Does it mean anything?

Comment: @ikegami I don't have this var in the env var. the output of echo $perl5lib is null

Comment: Please show full output of broken script (Use gists etc.). May be it's unrelated to Perl itself.

Comment: I didn't say `$perl5lib`; I said `$PERL5LIB`

Answer (score 0):

You can install your own Perl in home directory through https://perlbrew.pl/

It installs chosen Perl, and allows to run any script through specified perl (location of installed perl available through `perlbrew info`, and please, RTFM).